# Searching for simple variable names like 'c' or 'x' in Emacs

Tags: regex, emacs

I often wish to search for variables that are simply called 'c' or 'count'.

For example

```
int c, count;
```

Unfortunately when I use an incremental search for 'c' or 'count' I get a lot of unnecessary hits like the 'c' in 'choice', or the 'count' in 'wordcount' which do not interest me. I know Emacs can do i-searches with regular expressions but I don't know the correct regular expression needed to match just 'c' and 'count'. These words are often surrounded by any number of white spaces. Anyone know the regex I can use to narrow my search?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `isearch-forward-regexp`, usually bound to <kbd>C-M-s</kbd>, and search for `\bc\b` or `\bcount\b`

Answer (score 6):

In Emacs23, there's <kbd>M-x isearch-forward-word</kbd> (bound to <kbd>M-s w</kbd>) which does takes care of the word boundary (at the front) for you.

```
M-s w count
```

And, another keyboard shortcut for Andrew Stein's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13029/andrew-stein) of using `isearch-forward-regexp` is <kbd>C-u C-s</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You want to search (isearch-forward-regexp) for your string with word-boundaries (`\b`) on either side:

```
\bc\b

\bcount\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have told you how to search for what you want.  Here's my advice: From now on, just ***`don't do it`*** -- don't create the *need* for such a search in the first place.

30 years ago I stopped using variable names such as `x` and `i`.  If a variable cannot or need not be named something more useful, then I just name it `xx` or `ii`.

This simple trick cuts down on a lot of silly regexp searching such as (correctly) described on this page.

And there's usually little excuse for *not* doing something like this. Often single letters are used just out of laziness, I think.  But that practice can mean more effort in the end.

Just a suggestion...

(Now obviously some letters are not so simply handled.  `nn`, for instance, is common in English words. Use your judgment.)